# Automatically opening PDF output report from ArcGIS web app?

Tags: arcgis-server, r, web-service, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-web-appbuilder

We have a custom tool that we built using the R-ArcGIS bridge. It queries a bunch of tables stored in a SQLite database and uses LaTeX to create a PDF report as the output.

Within ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro, the tool runs great and is programmed within the script to automatically open the saved PDF report using this code and it automatically opens fine:

```
system(paste0('open "', pdf.path, '"'))
```

We have created a geoprocessing tool from our server so that we can run this as a web app. It works great and saves the PDF file where we want. However, the PDF report that is generated is not being automatically opened as a popup when running it from the web application.

Any ideas for how to open a PDF saved on the server from the custom tool in the web app?

Comment: I think you need to provide a little more info about your web app before anyone can help you.  In a web environment, you just need to create a button/link to download the pdf from your web app.  For your GP tool, I'd suggest using an Output Parameter of a string type and set it to the url to your pdf file (which must be put on a web server).  Once your GP task completes, you can get the output of the GP tool (which is the url) and just do `window.open(url, '_blank');`